# Mezzanine ImportError when running tests

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, content-management-system, mezzanine

I have recently upgraded the version of Django from 1.5.5 to 1.6.2 and Mezzanine to 3.0.9.

When I run

```
python manage.py test
```

All the tests run without problem.

But When I run project specific tests using

```
python manage.py test <project-name>
```

Then I get ImportError. I get that its something to do with Circular Imports.

Here is the stack trace. Please help.

> ======================================================================
>
> > ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name DisplayableAdmin)
> >      ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py",
> >     line 411, in loadTestsFromName
> >         addr.filename, addr.module)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py",
> >     line 47, in importFromPath
> >         return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py",
> >     line 94, in importFromDir
> >         mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)   File "/Users/devarajn/repos/pari/pari/album/tests.py", line 8, in 
> >         from pari.album.admin import AlbumAdmin, AlbumImageInline   File "/Users/devarajn/repos/pari/pari/album/admin.py", line 2, in 
> >         from mezzanine.core.admin import TabularDynamicInlineAdmin   File
> >     "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/admin.py",
> >     line 4, in 
> >         from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 182, in 
> >         admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/boot/lazy_admin.py", line 26, in register
> >         super(LazyAdminSite, self).register(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 92, in register
> >         admin_class.validate(model)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 105, in validate
> >         validator = cls.validator_class()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py",
> >     line 20, in **init**
> >         models.get_apps()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> >     line 139, in get_apps
> >         self._populate()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> >     line 78, in _populate
> >         self.load_app(app_name)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> >     line 99, in load_app
> >         models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
> >     line 40, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py",
> >     line 63, in 
> >         patch_root_urlconf()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py",
> >     line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
> >         reverse('djdt:render_panel')   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
> >     line 480, in reverse
> >         app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
> >     line 310, in app_dict
> >         self._populate()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
> >     line 262, in _populate
> >         for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
> >     line 346, in url_patterns
> >         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> >     "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
> >     line 341, in urlconf_module
> >         self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
> >     line 40, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "/Users/devarajn/repos/pari/pari/urls.py", line 7, in 
> >         admin.autodiscover()   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/boot/**init**.py",
> >     line 77, in autodiscover
> >         django_autodiscover(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/**init**.py",
> >     line 29, in autodiscover
> >         import_module('%s.admin' % app)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
> >     line 40, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/forms/admin.py",
> >     line 24, in 
> >         from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin   File "/Users/devarajn/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/pari/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/admin.py",
> >     line 12, in 
> >         from mezzanine.core.admin import DisplayableAdmin, DisplayableAdminForm ImportError: cannot import name
> >     DisplayableAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-debug-toolbar module was causing the issue.

I rolled back from django-debug-toolbar v1.0.1 to v0.11.

This fixed the error.